# "import decimal" raises errors

Tags: python, module, decimal, pypdf

here's the code I am using

```
import os
import decimal
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader
path = r"E:\python\Real Python\Real Python\Course materials\Chapter 8\Practice files"
inputFileName = os.path.join(path,"Pride and Prejudice.pdf")
inputFile = PdfFileReader(file(inputFileName,"rb"))

print "Number of pages:", inputFile.getNumPages()
print "Title:", inputFile.getDocumentInfo().title
```

Now, when I run this code I am getting an error:
module 'object' has no attribute 'Number'

I took a screenshot of the whole output that I got
when I run the above code, with errors and everything.
so,please take a look and let me know what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: As I've said before,(it seems) your decimal module is broken..

Comment: well, so what should I do to solve this?
is there a way to have a new decimal module?

Comment: I don't know... Try this : `import numbers; print numbers.Number`  if you get an `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Number'`, then the problem is the numbers module..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's a printout of all numbers up to 50 that aren't divisible by 3. It's probably in a `numbers` module on `sys.path` that's shadowing the standard library `numbers`. See where it is:

```
import numbers
print numbers.__file__
```

Comment: Wow! this worked.
there was a numbers file that I had created earlier for solving an exercise and it seems that this file was being called instead of the numbers module. I changed the name of the numbers file and now, it's working properly. Thank you so much.